# Programming with multiple-monitors in c#

Tags: .net, winforms, screen, multiple-monitors

I am working on a windows form application using c# and I am using two monitor(touchScreen) in this application.There are a lot of forms on this app and I want to show some forms on second monitor.I can show the forms on the second monitor using 'Screen' class of .net but I want to make a process on the second screen.For example I am showing a register form on the second Monitor and user can fill the form on this screen.Also I sometimes need to show to one form on 2 monitors at the same time.

Any help?

Comment: _I can show the forms on the second monitor..._ So what's the problem?

Comment: The problem is I don't know that how to change the focus of monitors when the montior is changing also how to display same form on two monitors at the same time?

Comment: Focus is set on a Control, not on a screen. One Form on two screens  is not really possible, two copies of the same form could work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,you mean it is not possible while working on a form to show on two monitors simultaneously?

Comment: did u find solution ?

Comment: if the first screen has 1024 pixels, setting window left 1080 pixels goes into the second screen?